# Locale ignored in APLA Alexa Developer Console

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I'm new to developing skills with Alexa. I've followed the [Build Multi-turn Skills Tutorial with Alexa Conversations](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/get-deeper/tutorials-code-samples/build-multi-turn-skills-with-alexa-conversations/module-3) tutorial up to module 3.

Because I want to develop a skill only for German users I've altered the language settings in the Alexa developer console of my skill to only support German language.

I change the APLA code in the tutorial with the APLA with the "edit audio response" to this:

```json
{
    "type": "APLA",
    "version": "0.8",
    "mainTemplate": {
        "parameters": [
            "payload"
        ],
        "item": {
            "type": "Selector",
            "strategy": "randomItem",
            "items": [
                {
                    "type": "Speech",
                    "contentType": "text",
                    "when": "${environment.alexaLocale == 'de-DE'}",
                    "content": "Willkommen bei meiner App"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Speech",
                    "contentType": "text",
                    "when": "${environment.alexaLocale == 'de-DE'}",
                    "content": "Willkommen."
                },
                {
                    "type": "Speech",
                    "contentType": "text",
                    "when": "${environment.alexaLocale == 'en-US'}",
                    "content": "Welcome."
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

At the bottom of the console I see that my locale is set to German but when I preview the APL above the audio player always says "Welcome." with the English voice, the other two options are never triggered. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The audio response tool doesn't take in account the language of the website.
There are no ways to test the condition `environment.alexaLocale` in this tool.

To test it, update the code of your skill and test it either on the test tabyour skill in the developer console or directly on a real device. Just tested with your code, it works perfectly. Just not on the audio tool.